# why OpenService() doesn't work when I check a window service status?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a very confused issue all this afternoon, I want to check the windows service status by QueryServiceStatusEx, but always get 0. MSDN says

> "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended
>   error information, call GetLastError."

To get more error information, I call GetLastError, the error code is  1.

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE : The handle is invalid.

Here is my code, e.g. I check the window service :"Spooler", where is wrong in my code? Why I can't get the service SC_HANDLE by using OpenService()?

```
bool isServiceStart()
{
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS  status;
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
    SC_HANDLE schService;

    //get hadnle to the scm database
    schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
                NULL, //local machine
                NULL, //services acitive database
                SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS
                );
    if(NULL == schSCManager){
        qDebug() << "Open SCManager failed: " << (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return false;
    }

    //Get a hadle to the service
    QString serviceName = "Spooler";
    schService = OpenService(
                schSCManager, //database
                (LPCTSTR)serviceName.data(),
                SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
                );
    if(schService == NULL){
        qDebug() << "service doesn't exist: " << GetLastError();
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;
    if(!QueryServiceStatusEx(
                schService,
                SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
                (LPBYTE) &status,             // address of structure
                sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS),
                &dwBytesNeeded    // size needed if buffer is too small
                ))
    {
        qInfo() << "service status" << status.dwCurrentState;
    }else{
        qInfo() << "hahaha alway is 0" <<GetLastError();
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: As an aside, you are consistently calling `GetLastError` too late. You need to call it *immediately*, when it's documented to return a meaningful value. Do not intersperse it with any other code, that can both change and invalidate the return value of `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, you write `"hahaha alway is 0"` when `QueryServiceStatusEx` returns *non*-zero.

Either remove the `!` operator in the condition, or switch places of the outputs.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!   I work on this all the afternoon, always thought I use some wrong parameters!!!! what an idiot!!!